# Get first row in UDF on Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, function, databricks, user-defined-functions

I want to able to create a SQL UDF in Databricks where I just want to return the top row of a table after performing various steps in several CTEs. I know that the **limit 1** command will let me achieve this, however when I add it into a CTE, I get the following error:

```
[UNSUPPORTED_SUBQUERY_EXPRESSION_CATEGORY.ACCESSING_OUTER_QUERY_COLUMN_IS_NOT_ALLOWED] Unsupported subquery expression: 
Accessing outer query column is not allowed in this locationFilter (cast(serial#378 as int) = outer(serial_input#375))
```

Here is an example of what I'm referring too. The below syntax will only deploy if I comment out the limit 1 line.

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TestFunction(serial_input INT) 
RETURNS FLOAT
LANGUAGE SQL 
RETURN  

    with cte as (
        select serial, date, NumberofCounts
        from MYSQLTABLE
        where serial = serial_input
        limit 1
        )

  select max(NumberofCounts) from cte
```

I did think about using Row numbers as another approach to retrieve the first row in my cte, however it seems Databricks doesn't allow **row_number() over (partition by...)** neither as I get the same error.

Can someone explain why this is happening, and if there may be another workaround I haven't thought of?

Comment: Forgot to add that when I run the above code without creating a function, it will accept limit 1 and return the top row, before calculating the aggregate function. So it seems that you can't use limit in Databricks UDFs?

Comment: This is a documented limitation, https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-sql-function.html see the "RETURNS" entry. Surprising it's so tough to find a workaround though. It works if you change it to RETURN TABLE instead of FLOAT. Then you can get the scalar when you use it in your query ... but very ugly.

Comment: Interesting approach. I hadn't thought of RETURN TABLE as I deliberately created a scalar UDF.